# When using Entity Framework Generate Database From Model column naming doesn't match legacy database

Tags: entity-framework, model, roundtrip

I have a legacy database that I am trying to fit new code over and when I try and round trip the schema using Generate Database From Model, I am getting column name mismatches on some of the tables that don't have (and currently can't have) foreign keys in place.  When I generate the SQL, the column names on a Many-to-Many referential table get the main table name prepended to the ID columns:

```
-- Creating table 'GroupUser'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GroupUser] (
    [Groups_GroupID] int  NOT NULL,
    [Users_UserID] int  NOT NULL
);
GO
```

rather than the original (legacy):

```
-- Creating table 'GroupUser'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GroupUser] (
    [GroupID] int  NOT NULL,
    [UserID] int  NOT NULL
);
GO
```

There are many other columns getting similar 'upgrades' which is futzing with my stored procedures.  Is there a simple way to override this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

[Code First Data Annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg197525%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).  Specifically, [ColumnAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.columnattribute%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

Comment: Great link, but wouldn't that be Code First rather than Model First?  I am generating the initial model from the legacy database, then generating a SQL script from that model.  Where is the .cs file that I would update with the attributes?